# How do you skip over an array of JSON objects when randomly pulling data with fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, random, fetch

I'm creating an app that randomly pulls one of 40 objects from a JSON array in a JSON file (people.json) when a button is clicked. It works but will often pull duplicates. How would I go about skipping an object in the JSON file if that object has already been randomly called so that I can avoid duplicates?

Here is the data I have so far:

```
// Fetch random user and add money
async function getRandomUser() {
  const res = await fetch('people.json');
  const data = await res.json();

  let randomUser = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];

  addData(randomUser);
}

// Add new obj to data array
function addData(obj) {
  data.push(obj);

  updateDOM();
}
```

Comment: Can you not ask the API end point for a single person, where you pre-randomise the id you want, instead of getting _all_ people and then throwing most of that away again?

Comment: Yeah possibly, I'm not sure lol I'm following a Brad Traversy course but trying to change things along the way and running into issues. I just have a local JSON file that I'm pulling from.

Comment: in that case don't use `fetch`? load the json data, and then just pick a random element from the array in the same way that a million Stackoverflow answers for "pick random element from javascript array" already explain =)

Comment: Just pick serially then like traversing json array? Why are picking random elements if you don't want the same element to be picked up again.

Comment: Very simple in JS - add some object or array and check by indexOf on array or yourObject[newAdding] == undefined if you mark them by yourObject[newAdding] = something, but mind you cannot check something != undefined as it will not work, but !(something == undefined) will ;-)